# How can I display the username and password that i listed on radio button selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display the username and password of the specific row where the radio button is selected below on the label field also I want to store them in variables. So how can I achieve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TESTING</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>UserName</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>Select</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ram</td>
        <td>password1</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="radioButton1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Shyam</td>
        <td>password1</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="radioButton2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<label>The username is: </label>
<br>
<label>The password is: </label>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add any code to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service. It is up to you to show your efforts to solve an issue yourself and people help you fix **your code** when it doesn't work as expected

Comment: Can you suggest what to try?? Well I am noob at frontend.

Comment: "***Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.***" (from the [tour]) - if you're *neither* an enthusiast nor a professional this may not be the site for you. If you *are* an enthusiast then, I'm sorry, but we expect you to make an effort regardless of how new you may be.

Comment: Use `change` event to `get` the selected row i.e. `tr` and then use the `tr` to get `text` of required `td's`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are beginner so lets try this jquery code.

```
$('input[name=radioButton]').on('change', function () {
      if ($(this).val() == 'FirstUser') {
            $('.user').text($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text());
            $('.pass').text($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text());
    } else  {
            $('.user').text($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text());
            $('.pass').text($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text());
    }
});
```

Here [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/77p3nsaa/1/) link..

Comment: thanks alot I have been trying the onclick and onchange function but got stuck..and this worked like a charm..